# vee-validate - Validating child component from parent

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm using `vee-validate 3.x` I'd like to validate a form contained in a child component from the parent component.

### Parent

```
<form-wizard>
<tab-content :before-change="() => validateStep('firstStep')">
  <first-step ref="firstStep"></first-step>
</tab-content>
<tab-content>Step 2</tab-content>
```

### Child (firstStep)

```
<div>
    <ValidationProvider rules="required" ref="firstStep" v-slot="{ errors }">
      <input v-model="value" type="text" />
      <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </div>
```

Here is a minimum code reproduction of the issue

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-m17sn

I've got this error when validateStep is executed

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs[ref].validate is not a function"

### Question

I have the feeling the issue is related with `ref`, I've been looking around but did not manage to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent validation function looks like this:

```
validateStep(ref) {
  return this.$refs[ref].validate();
}
```

It would work if it looked like this:

```
validateStep(ref) {
  return this.$refs[ref].$refs[ref].validate();
}
```

The validate function is attached to the actual input of the child, not to the child component itself.  So the first `$refs[ref]` gets you to `firstStep.vue`, the component, the second `$refs[ref]` gets you to the internal input in `firstStep.vue`.  Also, in your codepen, you misspelled `ref="firtStep"` in `firstStep.vue`, so that didn't help.

I have a feeling you would be better served to have the `firstStep` form validation track it's own state and emit an event when the form is in a valid state.  That way if there's 10 fields in the form, the parent doesn't need to know anything about them, just that they were valid or not.

Comment: do you mind expanding on how you might emit the validation state from the child component using veeValidate. Thanks